# How to save and apply Excel file formatting from one to another Excel files?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here is the situation I am dealing with :
I have to export data from a Microsoft Access Database to an excel file (.xlsx) every day when new data is added. The problem is that I have to do formatting such as font or fill colors, column sizing and so on for the excel file every time when new one is exported. I wish I could save the formatting of my excel file somewhere and then to apply those formattings to my newly exported excel files.

Any idea to accomplish this?
Much appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have to do this a long time ago.  If you always apply the formatting in a consistent way, try recording your formatting steps as a macro you can play back.

Comment: thanks @ChrisDc for your idea . This can be an answer however I would like to keep this question open for further ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but once you set up the formatting how you want it on the first file, you can select all of the data inside, copy it, then in the new file (the one you want to format), select all of the data, right click, and choose the paste formatting option.

This relies on all your files coming out in the same general format though.

Comment: Currently I am using an empty (no data) excel file but with my desired formatting applied for a bunch of consequent rows. Then I copy data from the exported .xlsx and paste them (without formatting) on those already formatted rows in the new excel file. Unfortunately, I have to do formatting for sufficient number of rows before copying data for those rows. You may say that to overcome this I should apply formatting for entire rows available in the sheet but it seems (as I experienced) this slows down processing the document on smart phones where I need to work on it through the day.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is better to write a code to import the data from Access.
In VBA, you can specify what you will import and, after doing so, you can format what you just imported. Does  [it](http://www.askeygeek.com/vba-code-to-import-access-tablequery-data-to-excel/) help?

Comment: This isn't really an actionable solution.  It's more of a direction to investigate.  It would be more appropriate as a comment.